# Ubuntu 16.04 get stuck after Python 3 removal

Tags: 16.04, apt, python, uninstall, python3

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS seems stuck and has lost its graphical interface after the removal of python3. I thought only python2 was crucial for the System. However: how to fix this mess?
System does not answer to any command, I can only create a new document in a completely empty desktop. Trying to save it I see that my folders still exist. Combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> does not open terminal.
I tried with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` in the shell available during the recovery mode. It asks me to install 120MB of packages, but fails in fetching several of them. So it does nothing. 
Any help?

Comment: Note for future readers: Critical elements of your Ubuntu 16.04 system rely upon the version of Python3 shipped with Ubuntu. Do not remove it. Do not try to change the Py3 version.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
Maybe partially, with this procedure: once the OS is loaded, I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, this opening a prompt that asked me for my notebook credential. Then it gave me access to a shell.
The command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` did what it could not do during the recovery mode, due to the absence of connectivity. Hope this helps.